# Как найти нужную последовательность символов в Python и отделить лишнее?

Tags: python, строки

У меня есть 2 варианта вхождения символов:

```
'09-1103-2' и '09-1103-1-3'
```

Мне нужно написать регулярное выражение, после которого будет такой вывод:

```
['09-1103', '2'] и ['09-1103-1', '3'] соответственно
```

Первая строка в списке - нужная последовательность, вторая - лишний символ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
str.rsplit('-', 1)[0]
```

UPD:
Выражение разделяет строку на фрагменты по символу '-', начиная справа. Параметр "1" ограничивает количество разбиений, возвращая результат ['09-1103-1', '3']. Индекс в скобках указывает взять только нужную часть, первый элемент массива — '09-1103-1'.

Comment: А зачем тут `[0]`? И комментарии вовсе не лишние так то.

Comment: Отредактировал. Добавил пояснения. Думал что в базовых операциях со строками и массивами, и так должно быть всё понятно. Извините.

Answer (score 3):

Если у вас задача *именно* использовать регулярные выражения, то можно сделать так:

```
import re

def extr(a: str) -> list:
    return re.findall(r"(.+)-(\d+)$", a)

print(extr('09-1103-2'))
print(extr('09-1103-1-3'))
```

```
[('09-1103', '2')]
[('09-1103-1', '3')]
```

Обратите внимание, что метод `findall` вернет вам **список кортежей**.